# Swift 3 string comparison not working in if conditional statement

Tags: swift

I've this small piece of code. If the value is 0 then I want to go into if. This code never goes into if even if prints value 0. Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?

```
let value = (data?.object(forKey: "amount") as? String)!
print(String(describing: type(of: value)), value)
if value == "0" {
    print("if")
}else{
    print("else")
}
```

Print:
String 0 
else

Comment: Is `value` actually `"0 "`? Doing a `debugPrint` would make it clearer.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. "String 0" is not the same as `"0"`.

Comment: It could be that amount is being sent as Double from the response.

Comment: Tx Hamish. Yes that was the reason. Somehow I figured it out. Will remember debugPrint now.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I figured out that the string was actually "0 " which was not obvious from print().